# Is there a better version of something like acts_as_paranoid for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, soft-delete

Does anyone know of a gem that both soft deletes records from a database (just flags them as deleted as opposed to is actually deleted) and...

...also when do you any type of find automatically omits those trashed records without using any special user-defined scopes. E.g. it all takes place in the gem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to checkout paper_trail

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Answer (score 7):

DHH is a fan of doing this with 'concerns' which are basically just module mixins and I like that minimalist approach.

Here's DHH's version - https://gist.github.com/1014971

Here's my bugfixed version - https://gist.github.com/4032984

Answer (score 3):

## [Paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia)

The [Paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) gem from the overtly talented [Radar](https://github.com/radar) is what you'd be looking for.

It's essentially a rewrite of [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) (and uses many of the same conventions) but is smaller, faster and compatible with Rails 3 and 4.

It accomplishes both of your requests:

1. Automatically sets a `deleted_at` timestamp when a `destroy` method is called on an object whose class includes `acts_as_paranoid`.
2. Automatically sets a condition on any queries that ensure `deleted_at IS NULL`, unless you include `with_deleted` in your query chain.

Couldn't say enough good things about the library or Radar.

**Bonus: His documentation might be the best in the "business".**

Answer (score 2):

paper_trail has lots of features and is well tested (been around for a long time).

If you want just the specified functionality, check out:

https://github.com/grosser/soft_deletion

Answer (score 0):

I use Discard gem. It's a quite simple way for soft deletion records.
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/discard/1.0.0